# OpenAM cross domain cookie 'Iplanetdirectorypro' getting expired as response from IIS

Tags: single-sign-on, iis-8, setcookie, openam

Our application is protected with OpenAM web agent. We are encountering a situation where after the OpenAM is sending a post request with HTTP_REMOTELOGIN and Set cookie.But as response Iplanetdirectorypro cookie is getting expired. The issue came when the domain of our web site got changed from a.x--> a.y. Things are working perfectly for old URL domain.

Same configuration for the new domain is working on pre production and when the changes where done to Production, the web page after authentication from SSO is not properly loading due to the fact the OpenAM cookie is getting expired.

In the browser we can see the warning as "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and [https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032."](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.%22)

The issue is persisting on all web browsers.

We tried various things in IIS such as enabling CORS, disabling secure cookie setting but we had no luck.

So the question is whether OpenAM cookie managed somewhere in IIS which needs to be configured specific to the new domain.

Can anyone help !

Comment: You can try to set the SameSite=Lax.

Comment: Which 'OpenAM' fork / version is being used? Are you using host-based or domain cookies on OpenAM side? If domain cookies are used, does the cookie domain of OpenAM cover the one from the agent?

Comment: @samwu We have tried samesite=Lax as well as samesite=strict at IIS but no luck

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr OpenAM version is 13.5. it's a domain based cookie which is set by OpenAM. Yes, domain of OpenAM cookie is covered  one from the agent.

Comment: As it worked for the old URL / domain, it can not be related to 'sameSite'. Furthermore OpenAM Web Agent does not use CORS.